# How to convert a structure to a public structure with custom field types with MarshalJSON

Tags: json, go, interface, marshalling

I have a Type "Book" that i read from a different interface which returns json. After reading the json and processing data, i have to convert the book to a public book type to hide fields and change output format.

My problem is, that the input type from the same field (ISBN) is sometimes string and sometimes int. I thought that the easiest solution is to use json.Number to unmarshal the data. That works - but i need string on the outgoing json on different fields...

That is the point where i need help. I would have a custom type which i can set in the public structure at the fields, where i want to set the output-json-field to string. I named the custom type "mytype" in the example. (The real data are nested and i have more fields that i set to string in the output - the id field in the public structure is only a test)

I mean, it should look something like that - or not?

```
func (m *mytype) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    ...
}
```

Here is my example code: https://play.golang.org/p/rS9HddzDMp

```
package main 

import (  
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Definition of the internal Book object (read from input)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
type Book struct {
    Id                      json.Number         `json:"id"`
    Revision                int                 `json:"revision"`
    ISBN                    json.Number         `json:"isbn"`
    Title                   string              `json:"title"`
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Definition of the public Book object
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
type AliasBook Book
type omit           *struct{}
type mytype         string

type PublicBook struct {
    Id          string          `json:"id"`
    Revision    omit            `json:"revision,omitempty"`
    ISBN        mytype          `json:"isbn"`
    *AliasBook
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rendering functions
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func (bb *Book) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    fmt.Println("---------------MarschalJSON---------------")
    aux := PublicBook{
        Id:         bb.Id.String(),
        AliasBook:  (*AliasBook)(bb),
    }

    return json.Marshal(&aux)
}

func main() {
    var jsonStreams[2][]byte
    // Input ISBN as string
    jsonStreams[0] = []byte(`{"id":"123","revision":1234,"isbn":"978-3-86680-192-9","title":"Go for dummies"}`)
    // Input ISBN as int
    jsonStreams[1] = []byte(`{"id":123,"revision":1234,"isbn":9783866801929,"title":"Go for dummies"}`)

    // For each stream
    for i := range jsonStreams {
        fmt.Print("stream: ")
        fmt.Println(string(jsonStreams[i]))

        // Read Input
        b := Book{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(jsonStreams[i], &b)
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
        }

        // Output as JSON
        response := new(bytes.Buffer)
        enc := json.NewEncoder(response)
        enc.SetEscapeHTML(false)
        enc.SetIndent("", "    ")
        err = enc.Encode(&b)
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", response)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", response)
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I have a solution which works for me. https://play.golang.org/p/Vr4eELsHs1

The keypoint was, that i have to take "fmt.Sprint(*isbn) to return the string in the marshaler. I created a new type, convert the input to int64 with the json.Number function and convert it with the json custom marshaler to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution which works for me. https://play.golang.org/p/Vr4eELsHs1

The keypoint was, that i have to take `fmt.Sprint(*isbn)` to return the string in the marshaler. I created a new type, convert the input to int64 with the json.Number function and convert it with the json custom marshaler to string.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to have a custom type that represents ISBN numbers. You can then implement custom JSON decoding functionality so that you can parse both string & numeric input. For example

```
type isbn string

func (s *isbn) UnmarshalJSON(buf []byte) error {
    // Read numeric characters only from raw JSON input. This will handle strings, numbers or null etc and strip any
    // optional separators.
    out := make([]byte, 0, len(buf))
    for _, b := range buf {
        if b >= '0' && b <= '9' {
            out = append(out, b)
        }
    }

    // Validate ISBN (assuming not using old 10 digit ISBN)
    l := len(out)
    if l != 13 {
        return errors.New("Invalid ISBN length")
    }
    // Calculate check digit and ensure valid.

    // Create formatted output. This assumes 13 characters for simplicity
    *s = isbn(fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s-%s-%s-%s", out[:3], out[3:4], out[4:9], out[9:12], out[12:]))
    return nil
}
```

The above just stores the ISBN in a format suitable for output. However, you could store in any format and have a separate [json.Marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) implementation to format the output if this was required.

Then you can simply make this a field in your `Book` as normal:

```
type Book struct {
    Id       json.Number `json:"id"`
    Revision int         `json:"revision"`
    ISBN     isbn        `json:"isbn"`
    Title    string      `json:"title"`
}
```

*The ISBN decoding example above is for illustration purposes*. You should create a full implementation that is unit tested to ensure it handles all expected input correctly and raises the appropriate errors on empty/malformed input. The performance could also be improved if this was an issue.

**EDIT**

You can't call `json.Marshal` inside your `json.Marshaler` implementation with the same variable. This will cause an infinite recursive loop, e.g.

`json.Marshal(e)` -> `e.MarshalJSON` -> `json.Marshal(e)` -> `e.MarshalJSON` ...

The `json.Number` type is a string representation of a number. If you are simply wanting to output all numbers as strings, you don't need any custom types at all. Simply use the relevant string values in your code. For example:

```
type PublicBook struct {
    Id          string          `json:"id"`
    // all other fields...
}

// Creates the public book representation from a book
func Public(b *Book) *PublicBook {
  return &PublicBook{
     Id: string(b.Id),
  }
}
```

This will always output a string as you are using the `string` type and not the `json.Number` type which has custom JSON marshal/unmarshal implementations.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your reply!
ISBN is only a example for my problem. I do not need a special type in the Book struct i think. Because the unmarshal work with json.Number. But i need a unmarshal function that return everytime the value from my field - which i marked with "mytype" - as string. In this case it is the ISBN field. I began to write a function but i get errors, or emtpy output or get into a loop... Do you know, how i should write that?
Example:
type mytype string
func (e mytype) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    fmt.Printf("bla: %v\n", e)
    return json.Marshal(e)
}

Comment: I see, you were asking about the general case of always outputting a string. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!
i have a big nested structure with different json.Number fields. I yould only have to define a private and a public structure and would not build up the whole structure in the output again to stringify every field i need. Thats why i am thinking to have a custom type which i only have to define in the public structure. Every field with this type should be a string on the output. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: But why create a custom type when you can simply use the `string` type itself? You could still go do the composition approach as per your book MarshalJSON above if you wanted, you already have the ID output as a string.

Comment: Because in this case i need to define the public type twice: 
"type public struct" and then again in the output to allocate the value. So if it is possible to define only a custom type in the public struct, i do not have to allocate every value in the output because the marshal function should do that for me.

Comment: You're still going to need to do this twice. You can put a custom type in the public struct but this is in no way connected to the field in your embedded struct. `json.Marshal` will output the empty field in your public struct and skip the embedded struct due to having the same name. However, this field will always be empty unless you assign it a value. Remember, your public type actually has two fields with the same name! See https://play.golang.org/p/pWd_C3RddU to illustrate this.

Comment: Right, but i copy my private data to the public struct with the same field-names but different types. So the public struct should not be empty right? Se in my example the function "MarshalJSON" with the AliasBook

Comment: Your function doesn't copy data from one struct to the other, it simply provides the pointer to the embedded struct. Hence why the public struct fields are empty, you never assign these a value. Please re-read the trivial example again, it illustrates how the field in the struct is totally separate from the field in the embedded struct. Remember, if you access a field in an embedded struct that is not redeclared in the outer struct, this is just "syntactical sugar". For example, `outer.Name` is equivalent to `outer.inner.Name`.

Comment: You are right...hmmm...i tought about that. The only thing i need is the "string" function on a json.Number field...
ISBN json.Number `json:"isbn,string"`

Comment: I have tested a new version of my program. I take the unmarshal function to convert my input to integer. But if i set ",string" to my isbn i get a "0" value in the second example when the isbn input is a number:
[https://play.golang.org/p/pqLY7LuLOD](https://play.golang.org/p/pqLY7LuLOD)